# Image Height now changing with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, height

I'm trying to change the height and width of an image when clicked on a certain button. So far I got the basics, but I think I don't have them in the right order. The image and the other text are moving, but the image size isn't changing. Right now it mostly the white space around the image changing.

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script>

  //image
  function shrinkImage() {
    $('#dog_image').height(200);
    $('#dog_image').width(307);
  }

  </script>
</head>

<div id="dog_image">
<img src="dog.jpg" alt="turle">
</div>

<div id="image_buttons">
  <button type="button" id="shrink" onclick="shrinkImage();">Shrink Image</button>
</div>
```

Comment: try `$('#nickel_image').css.height(450);`

Comment: You are changing div height width, not image's height width.

Comment: Your code can be good and no need to change, if you set image css `width: 100%` and `height:100%`

Comment: @boussadjrabrahim didn't work. I'm trying to change the dimensions of the image

Comment: @AliShahbaz didn't work. I'm trying to change the dimensions of the image

Answer (score 0):

Here's a nice way to do that :

```js
$('.pictureclass').click(function (e) {
    if ($(e.target).hasClass('expanded')) {
        $(".pictureclass").removeClass('expanded').stop().animate({
            width: 300,
            height: 300
        }, 300);
    } else {
        $(".pictureclass").addClass('expanded').stop().animate({
            width: $(e.target).attr("width"),
            height: $(e.target).attr("height")
        }, 200);
    }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<img id="mrbean" class="pictureclass" src="http://2.bp.blogspot.com/-C6KY8tsc8Fw/T-SVFnncxjI/AAAAAAAAANw/FMiNzA8Zecw/s640/mr.bean.jpg" width="50" height="50" />
```

Answer (score 0):

This isn't you want?

```css
img{
width: 100%;
height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script>

  //image
  function shrinkImage() {
    $('#nickel_image').height(200);
    $('#nickel_image').width(307);
  }
  function enlargePic() {
    $('#nickel_image').height(450);
    $('#nickel_image').width(580);
  }
  function restorePic() {
    $('#nickel_image').height(300);
    $('#nickel_image').width(460);
  }
  </script>
</head>

<div id="nickel_image">
<center><img src="https://www.w3schools.com/w3css/img_lights.jpg" alt="turle"></center>
</div>

<div id="image_buttons">
  <p>Image:</p>
  <button type="button" id="shrink" onclick="shrinkImage();">Shrink Image</button>
  <button type="button" id="enlarge" onclick="enlargePic();">Enlarge Pic</button>
  <button type="button" id="restore" onclick="restorePic();">Restore Pic</button>
</div>
```